# Menu fadeIn on click works. But fadeOut on click does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a "hamburger" icon as a button, that when clicked, fades the menu into view.  When I try and assign the fadeOut to another icon/button within the menu, it does not work, and the menu stays visible indefinitely, cannot be hidden unless the page is refreshed.

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".acetrnt-toggle-button").click(function(){
    $("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeIn();

    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".acetrnt-overlay-close").click(function(){
    $("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeOut();

    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">

            <button class="acetrnt-toggle-button"><icon class="fa fa-bars"></icon></button>

            <h2 class="rp-heading">Recent Posts</h2>

            <div id="acetrnt-toggle-overlay">

                <button class="acetrnt-overlay-close"><icon class="fa fa-close"></icon></button>

                <nav class="site-nav-primary">

                    <?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary'); ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>

                </nav>

            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS code:

```
/* Toggle Menu */

#acetrnt-toggle-overlay {

position: fixed;
display: none;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
z-index: 2;
color: #fefefe;
font-family: raleway;
font-size: 3rem;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 50px;

}

#acetrnt-toggle-overlay a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fefefe;

}

#acetrnt-toggle-overlay li {

    list-style: none;

}


.acetrnt-toggle-button {

    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 8rem;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.fa fa-bars {

    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 3rem;

}

.fa fa-close {

    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 3rem;

}

.acetrnt-overlay-close {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
```

If you have any ideas, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation();

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".acetrnt-toggle-button").click(function(){
$("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeIn();

});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".acetrnt-overlay-close").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
$("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeOut();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js looks wrong, you don't need two document ready, replace it with the code below

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $(".acetrnt-toggle-button").click(function(){
  $("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeIn();

  });

  $(".acetrnt-overlay-close").click(function(){
  $("#acetrnt-toggle-overlay").fadeOut();

  });
});
```

and make sure to add jquery in the html file, check the working sample https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBWdbg

Comment: // I just tried that, and I am having the same issue.  But it was a good thought!  I also do have the latest jquery added in my html.

Comment: That's exactly what I want it to do!  So, obviously something else in my code is conflicting with it.  :(  I did change it so that both are within the same document ready.

Comment: If you can create a codepen or fiddle with the code that is conflicting, others would be able to help you

Comment: It is my entire wordpress website, it would be a huge amount of code.  It could be anything.  I thought maybe there was just something wrong with my jquery or css, but no, it works perfect.